# Worst Time Complexity of Talks Scheduling

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question is to find the worst case time complexity of a brute-force algorithm for scheduling the talks by examining all possible subsets of talks.

Suppose we have $n$ talks that we want to schedule using greedy algorithm. There is a theorem which says that $n$ elements could give $2^n$ subsets. So, we have a combination of $2^n$ talks. Then we an compare $n\times(n-1)\times2^n$ pairs of talks and thus the worst-case complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n\times(n-1)\times2^n)$.

Each pair of talks in a subset have to be compared against each other to check for overlapping. There are $n$ talks and thus there are $n\times(n-1)$ pairs of (distinct) talks.

**Question:** Could you please explain why there are $n\times(n-1)$ pairs of (distinct) talks?

Comment: There are $n(n-1)$ **ordered** pairs of distinct talks: the first member of the pair can be any of the $n$ talks, and the second can be any of the other $n-1$ talks. There only half that many **unordered** pairs of distinct talks, however, since if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are distinct talks, the first calculation counts the pairs $\langle t_1,t_2\rangle$ and $\langle t_2,t_1\rangle$ separately.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thank you Doctor. I am still not sure why $n\times(n-1)$ ordered pairs?

Comment: Make a small example. Say that there are just $3$ talks, $A,B$, and $C$. The ordered pairs are $\langle A,B\rangle$, $\langle A,C\rangle$, $\langle B,A\rangle$, $\langle B,C\rangle$, $\langle C,A\rangle$, and $\langle C,B\rangle$. Split them up into $3$ groups according to their first element: one group has $\langle A,B\rangle$ and $\langle A,C\rangle$, one has $\langle B,A\rangle$ and $\langle B,C\rangle$, and the third has $\langle C,A\rangle$ and $\langle C,B\rangle$. Each of these $3$ groups has $2=3-1$ members, because each of the $3$ possible first elements can be paired with either ...

Comment: ... of the two remaining elements, so we get a total of $3\cdot2=6$ ordered pairs. Now just replace $3$ by $n$ and $2$ by $n-1$: the reasoning is exactly the same.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thank you Doctor. So, distinct talks is same as ordered pairs?

Comment: No, *distinct talks* just means that we’re not pairing any talk with itself. Notice that in my example I counted $\langle A,B\rangle$ and $\langle B,A\rangle$ as different pairs even though the involve exactly the same two talks; that’s because I’m taking the order in which I list them into account — hence **ordered** pairs. If I just look at the possible **sets** (**un**ordered pairs) of two talks, I get only $3$: $\{A,B\}$, $\{A,C\}$, and $\{B,C\}$. Now I pay no attention to the order in which they’re listed, but only to which talks they are: $\{A,B\}$ is the same two talks as $\{B,A\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Prof, could you please explain why we multiply with $2^n$ by the distinct pairs we have $n(n-1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grind through it.

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of exactly $k$ talks to consider, to check a $k$ set for overlaps means considering $k (k - 1) / 2$ pairs (pick first element in $k$ ways, there are $k - 1$ options for the second one; but the order $a, b$ is the same a $b, a$, thus the $2$). Or just $\binom{k}{2} = k (k - 1) / 2$ pairs.

So in all there are $W$ comparisons:

$\begin{align*}
   W
     &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{k (k - 1)}{2}
\end{align*}$

Quite a mouthful.

Consider:

$\begin{align*}
    f_m(x)
      &= (1 + x)^m \\
      &= \sum_{0 \le k \le m} \binom{m}{k} x^k \\
    f_m''(x)
      &= m (m - 1) (1 + x)^{m - 2} \\
      &= m (m - 1) \sum_{0 \le k \le m - 2} \binom{m - 2}{k} k (k - 1) x^{k - 2}
\end{align*}$

Time to relate to your sum:

$\begin{align*}
   \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{k (k - 1)}{2}
     &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} k (k - 1) \\
     &= \frac{1}{2} f_{n + 2}''(1) \\
     &= \frac{1}{2} (n + 2) (n + 1) \cdot 2^{n + 2} \\
     &= (n + 2) (n + 1) \cdot 2^{n + 1}
\end{align*}$

Now for the $O(\cdot)$ part. It is easy to see that:

$\begin{align*}
   (n + 2) (n + 1) \cdot 2^{n + 1}
      &= O(n^2 \cdot 2^n) \\
      &= O(n (n - 1) \cdot 2^n)
\end{align*}$

Comment: Thank you Doctor.

Comment: @Avra, $2^n = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k}$ is the complete set.

Comment: Thank you again. Amazing explanation, but needed sometime to get through it though!

Comment: @Avra, chek out e.g. Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), paricularly the technique he calls "snake oil".

Comment: Thank you Doctor.

Comment: Hello again! Back to your example please, @Brian M. Scott has mentioned as I understood that we need distinct talks (order matters), so we should not divide $(k)(k-1)/2$ but we should have each time $k(k-1)$. What do you think please?

Comment: Do you multiple $\binom{n}{k}$ $\frac{k (k - 1)}{2}$ because you are taking each time distinct talks ordered $\frac{k (k - 1)}{2}$ as a fraction of all talks each step $\binom{n}{k}$ please?

Comment: Also Prof., you took derivative of $f_m(x)$ with respect to $x$ please? In $f_m(x)''$ we have $x^{k-2}$, not sure why?